# SSH banner not showing

Tags: sshd

I have a fresh installation of OpenSSH. In the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have the following entry:

`Banner /etc/issue.net`

I have restarted the SSH deamon using: `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`. Now, whenever I try to run `ssh user@localhost` it works just fine, except it doesn't show the pre-login banner.

What can cause this problem?

Comment: Any output in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/secure` (depending on your distro)?

Comment: @SailorCire `/var/log/syslog` (Ubuntu 14.04) doesn't show anything related to SSH.

Comment: Improper permissions on /etc/issue.net?

Comment: @mdpc and what are the proper permissions?

Comment: The problem is "selinux". I ran "setenforce 0" and the banner was displayed. Now, the real problem is finding a solution, other than disabling selinux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 uses `upstart`, and `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` doesn't restart `sshd` if `upstart` is running, so `sshd` isn't recognizing your changes to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Instead, run this:

```
# restart ssh
```

You can verify that sshd was restarted by running

```
# ps -f -p $(pgrep sshd)
```

or

```
# ps -f -p $(status ssh | awk '{ print $NF }')
```

and checking that the start time (STIME) is more recent than the time you ran the command to restart it.

Answer (score 6):

Possibilities:

1. sshd is reading a different config file from the one you've edited
2. sshd is running in a chroot environment which doesn't include the file you specified
3. sshd didn't really restart, perhaps because you have systemd and the init script for ssh exits when it realises upstart isn't running (in this case, use `systemctl restart ssh.service`).
4. You're using ssh protocol 1 instead of 2.

Comment: I can confirm it's not 1, 2 or 4. How can I check 3rd possibility?

Answer (score 3):

I did not see mentioned here, but even if the banner is enabled in `sshd_config` and sshd is fully restarted, the user's own `~/.ssh/config` can suppress the banner using:

`LogLevel QUIET`

As the op took the solution but noone mentioned this, I'd like to add that here for future searchers

Comment: This happened to me. I had `LogLevel ERROR` set in `~/.ssh/config`, and I thought the Banner was broken. It was just being hidden!